# Azure Basic Tier DTUs - Different Rates for Basic Tier (B DTUs)

Tags: sql, database, azure

According to the following link: [Azure Database Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/) the hourly rate for a Basic Tier DTU service plan for a single database model is priced at $0.0068.

The recent billing invoice for my (Pay as you go) Subscription stated that the hourly rate for a 'Single Basic B DTUs' SQL Database is listed as $0.1610.

Without trying to get ahold of Microsoft, does someone know why their site advertises the basic DTU hourly rate at one price and have a different rate on invoices? Not sure if anyone has encountered something like this, just trying to get an idea why there was a change?

Any guidance or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your invoice, that price is quite close to the $0.1613 S7 plan. Also note the price varies per region, so check the region as well. If you still can't come up with an explanation, simply open up a support ticket from within the Azure portal, they typically respond in a reasonable time and will happily resolve billing discrepancies.

Comment: I verified the region pricing by using the pricing calculator with the region we used for our account. I submitted a ticket to Microsoft, thank you for the recommendation.